# python imagetk can not open images in same directory

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I used imageTk to open images for my GUI but I have an error "No such file or directory" And I'm sure where I keep my python script and images in same directory. What I do wrong ? Help me please. Thank you so much.

Comment: You must assume the error message is telling you the truth. Are you giving a fully qualified path to the function? Are you running the script after cd'ing to the folder with the images, or are you running it from another directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to include the file extension as well as the full path when loading the image? It would help if we could see some of your code otherwise we can do nothing other than guess at your issue.